# postscript store large amounts of data

Tags: postscript

I am creating a postscript program that needs to be able to process up to ten million data points. I am having troubles storing this data in the file. Here is a simplified version of what I have right now:

% (data and calls to process)
datapoint<sub>1</sub> datapoint<sub>2</sub> ... datapoint<sub>n</sub> process
datapoint<sub>n+1</sub> datapoint<sub>n+2</sub> ... datapoint<sub>2n</sub> process
...
datapoint<sub>(m-1)n+1</sub> ... datapoint<sub>mn</sub> process

Process is function that takes points on the stack and does computations on them resulting in various lines being drawn on the page. Because the stack has a maximum number of points that can be put on it I have to split the data up into chunks for processing. This is fine however I'd like to process this data twice in 2 different ways (and later on, possibly more than 2 ways). My original plan was to do the following. I would have 2 functions, process1 and process2 and the process function would be replaced with this:

```
/process{
  mode 1 eq{process1}if
  mode 2 eq{process2}if
} def
```

and then I'd put the entire list of data and calls to the process function inside some other function called "processData" like this for example.

```
/processData{
  datapoint1 ... datapointn process  
  ...
  datapointnm process
}def
```

then I'd be able to do both types of processing like so:
/mode 1 def processData
/mode 2 def processData

The advantage of this would be I wouldn't need to write out all the data again which would take up far too much space, especially once I need to do multiple process (not just 2). This doesn't work however because just like the stack there is a max size on the number of things that can go in a function.

My second plan was to instead put the data in an array and then loop through the data twice like so:

```
/array [datapoint1 datapoin2 ... datapointmn] def
1 1 n m mul {array exch get process1} for
1 1 n m mul {array exch get process2} for
```

However this doesn't work either because arrays have a maximum length also. I then tried to encode the data as chars and put it all in a string but strings also have a maximum length. I am considering using an array of strings however I suspect there is a better way of doing this.

How can this be done? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you really simply want the data stored in the file, and have the PostScript program read it from there. I can't see any reason for storing the data as part of the program. You can use the 'token' operator to read PostScript objects from the file, so you can just store the data as (I presume) numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ken's comment is a good idea, so this answer is to flesh it out a little.

You can put your data points in an external file and access it in the main program in several different ways. Assuming the file is named `datapoints.ps` you cam use the `run` operator to read-in the file.

```
/mode 0 def  (datapoints.ps) run
/mode 1 def  (datapoints.ps) run
```

Or you could read "chunks" from the file and process them separately. One number at a time:

```
/f (datapoints.ps) (r) file def
{
    f token not {exit} if
    dup process1
    dup process2
    pop
} loop
```

Line at a time:

```
/tokens {
    { token not {exit} if exch } loop
} def
/f (datapoints.ps) (r) file def
f 1000 string 
{
    {readline} stopped {
        pop length 2 mul string
    }{
        not {exit} if
        tokens
        count copy process1
        count copy process2
        clear
        f 1000 string
    } ifelse
} loop
```

This could be simpler if you know the maximum line length you need to deal with.

I hope this gives you some ideas. The description in the question is a little vague, so any more details you can give will help us to give you better suggestions.

Another option might be **arrays of arrays**. An implementation may have limits on the length of arrays. I don't actually know the limit in ghostscript since I recently learned it was much higher than the 65536 that I thought it was. But say the limit is 50000. And you have 100000 items.

So split the data into 2 50000-element arrays. There is no limit on the level of nesting that you can have. In fact an array can contain itself, in effect *infinite nesting*.

If you have 10 million, you could have 3 levels, 10 x 1000 x 1000

```
[
  [
    [ n0 ... n999  ]
    [ n1000 ... n1999 ]
    ...
    [ n999000 ... n999999 ]
  ]
  [
    [ n1000000 ... n1000999 ]
    ...
  ]
  ...
  [
    [ n9000000 ... n9000999 ]
    ...
    [ n9999000 ... n9999999 ]
  ]
]
```